# Why is liquid a countable noun?

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I read this sentence in a description to a podcast from https://www.eslpod.com/website/index_new.html

> Batter, “batter,” when we talk about cooking is **a** liquid, made usually
>   with eggs, and flower, and perhaps milk, and you combine these things
>   together and you get **a thick liquid**, which we call batter

Why do I need to use *a* before *liquid*? What makes liquid countable?

Comment: I believe it is both count and non-count depending on the use.

Comment: Not all liquids are "batter".

Comment: Water is a liquid.  Batter is a liquid.  Beer is a liquid.  Urine is a liquid.  Bromine is a liquid.  Liquid iron is a liquid.  My bath contains 90l of liquid.  If I added another 40l of water then there would be more liquid in the bath.  If I poured a gallon of batter and a gallon of beer into the bath and had a 'little accident' in the bath then there would be more liquid*s* in the bath.

Comment: Answered at [When do you use the plural form for nouns that are generally considered uncountable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169367/when-do-you-use-the-plural-form-for-nouns-that-are-generally-considered-uncounta/169423#169423) (JL actually gives the example 'liquid').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do you use the plural form for nouns that are generally considered uncountable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169367/when-do-you-use-the-plural-form-for-nouns-that-are-generally-considered-uncounta)

Comment: There are votes to reopen this question. I'm adding my vote too, so that we can then either **close** it again, *as a duplicate of the question referred to in the comments*, or close the other one as a dupe of this, or even merge the two questions. This will ensure that users finding either question can be directed to the full range of answers. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Catija mentions in the comments, "liquid" may be used both ways, as a non-count noun or as a count noun.

Many nouns that are otherwise non-count (let's use "X" to stand for an example noun) may be used as count nouns with the implication being "a specific type of noncount noun X".

This seems to apply to most words for states of matter. We can speak of "liquid," "gas," "fluid" but we can also speak of "a liquid," "a gas," "a fluid", as in "water is a liquid", "carbon dioxide is a gas".

Other examples: "red wine" (uncountable) vs. "a red wine" (countable), "vapo(u)r" (uncountable) vs. "a vapo(u)r" (countable).

A good learner's dictionary should list such nouns as being able to be used in both ways, countable and uncountable.

This might not be a very satisfying answer, but in general it's not easy to predict if a word will be countable or uncountable just from the meaning.  "Fruit" is generally non-countable, while "vegetable" is countable. "Peas" is countable, but "corn" is non-countable. "Furniture," "silverware" and "clothing" are non-countable, although we can have singular items of any of these.

In a comment below another question, [John Lawler wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114865/term-for-uncountable-nouns-mass-nouns-which-are-sometimes-countable?rq=1):

> Virtually all mass nouns can be used as if they were count nouns under
> certain circumstances, and vice versa.

Another question that might be of use: [When can you pluralize uncountable nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94082/when-can-you-pluralize-uncountable-nouns?rq=1) (As far as I know, any nouns that can be pluralized can also be preceded by the singular indefinite article "a".)

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes words are left out when the meaning is clearly understood. This is especially true with many uncountable nouns, also called *[mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)*, and countable ones ([count noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)). You need to look up the word in a dictionary to check if it can be used either way. For example,

- I would like a **cup of** espresso, please = I'd like **an espresso**, please.
- He drank fourteen **pints of** beer last night = He drank **fourteen beers** last night.
- There are many **types of** wine I enjoy = There are **many wines** I enjoy
- Batter, "batter", [...] is a **type of thick** liquid = Batter [...] is **a** (thick) **liquid**

> **coffee**
>   <sub><sup>[MASS NOUN]</sup></sub>
>   **1.** A hot drink made from the roasted and ground bean-like seeds of a tropical shrub: *a cup of coffee*
>   **1.1.** <sub><sup>[COUNT NOUN]</sup></sub> A cup of coffee:
>   *we went out for a coffee*
>
> <sub><sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coffee)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 5):

Noncountable nouns have countable uses, e.g.,

> I'd like to order **a** beer.

Beer, being a liquid, is noncountable; however, "a beer," means a serving of beer, which is countable.

But this is independent of whether noncountable nouns take articles.  They may do so even when they're used in a noncountable context:

> The company produces **a** beer without alcohol.

This does not mean that the company produces only a single serving.

> **The** beer served at the party was non-alcoholic.

Nor does this mean that the hosts served only a single serving.

We're not talking about individual servings here, but about noncountable amounts of liquid.  The first sentence talks about a general category (thus using the indefinite article), and the second talks about a specific classification (thus using the definite article).

Comment: Your second example would seem to be using "beer" as a countable noun to refer to specific *kinds of* beer. Compare: "The company produces two non-alcoholic beers: a light lager and a darker variant." But then, arguably, that's true for "liquid" in the OP's quote, too.

Comment: I agree with Ilmari -- liquid here seems to be countable because it is "a (kind/type of) liquid." This seems to be the case for all examples in answers here where people are using "a" with uncountables.

Comment: In your last sentence, "the beer served at the party was non-alcoholic," how can we tell if "the beer" is countable or non-countable? The definite article is the same either way, right?

Comment: @sumelic Context.  If it's countable, "the beer" means one serving of beer, either a bottle, a can, or a stein.  What kind of party is it where the host offers only one serving of beer to all of his guests?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that there are two types of countable "beer": serving-size is one, but "beer" referring to a type of beer is also countable. "The company produces a beer without alcohol" can be pluralized to "The company produces **beers** without alcohol" or "the company produces **three beers** without alcohol." So I guess I think you're mistaken when you call this a "noncountable context." I think my position agrees with what Ilmari is saying also.

Comment: You guess you think that, eh?  OK, how many of the beer did the host serve?

Comment: I'd only expect that sentence to work if "beer" was a collective noun. It clearly isn't. That's different from the mass/count distinction though. We can say, for example, "How many beers does the company produce without alcohol?" What I'm saying is that for me, "beer" is unambiguously countable in your second example sentence. I don't know whether it's countable or uncountable in your third example sentence; I'm trying to find out a good way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

This is the entry from Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary where it's stated to be both countable and uncountable. There is no any example however.
Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, 8th edition

li • quid   noun,   adjective 
BrE   / lɪkwɪd / 
NAmE   / lɪkwɪd /

noun

word origin 
 thesaurus 
 example bank 
  [ uncountable ,  countable ]
a substance that flows freely and is not a solid or a gas, for example water or oil 
 She poured the dark brown liquid down the sink. 
  the transition from liquid to vapour 
   see also  washing-up liquid

**© Oxford University Press, 2010**

In the example bank section, I've found the following sentence. We can make conclusions now, I guess.

*Immiscible liquids such as oil and water do not mix*.

As can be seen, the very word is used in plural which means it has singular form used with the article A as well. I guess, If the topic is about the different kinds of the substance, then it's accepted to use the word as a countable noun.